# Referring to columns by index not by name

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

### Background

I have a survey table as follows

```
E313     B515       C515      ...   (more columns)
1122     John doe   I don't like the lesson
2211     Mary Jane  It was excellent
```

The survey provider also provided labels for decoding the columns in the survey as follows (`survey_data_map.csv`):

```
Code    Label
E313    Unique Identifier
B515    Full name
C515    Feedback
.
.
.
(more rows)
```

So I have written a little snippet that decodes columns in the survey to the column labels.

```
survey_data_map <- read.csv("survey_data_map.csv")
for(i in 1:length(names(survey))) {
  
  label <- survey_data_map$Label[survey_data_map$Code == names(survey)[i]]
  if (length(label) > 0) {
    names(survey)[i] <- label  
  }
}
```

### Question

The column names in the `survey_data_map.csv` that decodes column name may change.
My question is how do I re-write the for-loop to use column indexes instead of using column names `Code` and `Label`?

Thank you.

Comment: Two things: (1) *why* do you want this? Using column names is almost certainly superior to using numeric indices here. What’s the actual problem you’re trying to solve? (2) Don’t make things more complicated than they need to be, and make use of R’s vectorisation. The entire loop can be rewritten as `names(survey) <- survey_data_map$Label[match(survey_data_map$Code, names(survey))]`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thanks for the reply. I guess my answer is, my lack of experience with R. The actual problem I am trying to solve? What if the provider changes the column names of the `survey_data_map.csv`.
Thanks for pointing out `match()`. Something new to learn today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, columns of a data frame can be addressed with the [`[[` subset operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). You can use either the numeric index or the name (as a character string) to do so:

```
survey_data_map[[1L]] # same as
survey_data_map[['Code']]
```

However, be sure that this is what you should actually do! You wrote:

> What if the provider changes the column names of the `survey_data_map.csv`

And that’s indeed a valid concern! However, at least if this happens it’s likely that you’ll get an error. Conversely, another thing that also happens frequently is that somebody *reorders* the columns of a table. If this happens and you use column indices your code will continue to run but it will produce wrong results.

Comment: You're right. The survey provider might reorder the columns in the `survey_data_map.csv`. Thanks for bringing this up.